# Problem with vectors (tikz)

Tags: diagrams

[image]I have to draw these vectors, with the grid and also a grid (like the picture). I've searched online but I can't solve my problem. Can you help me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}

\usepackage[centering,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[color=gray]
%\draw[line width=0.10pt, step=1.0mm] (0,0) grid +(20cm,28cm);
%\draw[line width=0.25pt, step=5.0mm] (0,0) grid +(20cm,28cm);
\draw[line width=0.05pt, step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid +(10cm,5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to draw the angle like the picture. And I would like to add color inside the angle.

Comment: You can start by reading the first tutorial in [TikZ' manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), and then add the missing picture to your post.

Comment: I've load the picture.

Comment: From a previous question of yours I see that you already know how to draw a grid with TikZ, why not add the code showing just the grid?

Comment: yes, you're right. I'll do it in 1 minute

Comment: @ryuk Please do *not* post code in comments. You should *edit* the question and insert there any update or modify existing test. Keep in mind that comments are 2nd class citizens on SE sites, and so you shouldn't rely on them. They are useful to clarify some aspect of a question or answer, but once that thing is clear the question/answer should be edited to include the point/clarification of the comments.

Comment: @Bakuriu The code in that comment was added to the question a long time ago after a (now deleted) comment of mine.

Comment: @ryuk I don't think it's nice to add a completely new question when there is an accepted answer already, better if you ask a new question.

Comment: ok! I'm so sorry. I'll do a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your MWE to picture below was just small step:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}

\usepackage[centering,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth]
\draw[gray,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(9cm,6cm);
    \draw[ultra thick,red, ->]  (1,4) -- node[above] {$\vec{a}$} +(2,0);
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->]  (1,3) -- node[below left] {$\vec{b}$} +(1,-2);
%
    \draw[ultra thick,red, ->]  (4,4) -- node[above] {$\vec{a}$} +(1,0);
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,->]  (4,4) -- node[below left] {$\vec{b}$} +(1,-2);
    %
    \draw[ultra thick,blue,|-|] (6,1) -- node[below] {$u$} +(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```